# How to use current location in dialog flow inline editor fulfillment?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

[image: FollowupIntent-withevent][image: How to read city from it ?]       In book movie use case ,Suppose user wants to book movie , and we want to get current city from him based on his current location .If I send in response a suggestion chip " Use My Location" simple plain text . If he clicks on it ,I want to extract user's city based on his current location. Could someone please suggest a solution for dialog flow fulfillment inline editor to get his current browsing city

```
function ask_for_permissions_detailed (agent)
{
  agent.requestSource = agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE;
  let conv = agent.conv(); 
  const options = { 
    context: 'BookMovie-SelectLocation', //which context ?
    permissions: ['NAME', 'DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION'],
  }; 
  conv.ask(new Permission(options)); 
}

let intentMap = new Map();
intentMap.set('BookMovie-SelectLocation', ask_for_permissions_detailed); 
agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
```

I called this **BookMovie-SelectLocation** intent and added followup intent to it with event in it Google Assitant permission ,which context do i need to pass in options context and what all changes do i need to do

Answer (score 1):

Actions on Google provides Helpers to get user information. You can request precise location of the user using the [User Information Helper](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers)

Sample code :

```
const {Permission} = require('actions-on-google');
app.intent('ask_for_permissions_detailed', (conv) => {
  // Choose one or more supported permissions to request:
  // NAME, DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION, DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION
  const options = {
    context: 'To address you by name and know your location',
    // Ask for more than one permission. User can authorize all or none.
    permissions: ['NAME', 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION'],
  };
conv.ask(new Permission(options));
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used below code but it did not work ,      
function ask_for_permissions_detailed (agent) {
  agent.requestSource = agent.ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE;
  let conv = agent.conv();
  const options = {
    context: 'location', //which context ?
    permissions: ['NAME', 'DEVICE_COARSE_LOCATION'],
  };
conv.ask(new Permission(options));
}
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('BookMovie-SelectLocation', ask_for_permissions_detailed);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});   After using above code i added follow up intent in which used event googlepermissionassitant , but it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments - its very difficult to read. Instead, update your question to show what you tried and what isn't working (including what errors you may be getting). The more you can show (what Intents you have, what code you're using, etc), the better chance we can help.

Comment: @Prisoner I have updated code with intents .Please suggest solution

Comment: What you show should work. What is it doing instead? You may want to show screen shots of the Intent and Followup Intent editing pages so we can confirm those are set correctly.

Comment: @Prisoner I have added followup intent (BookMovie-City) with event name (Google Assistant permission) in it .Please have a look  and Google assistant pic but  how to read those values of city in fulfillment As i want to display city name before "it is " as mentioned in second snapshot and whether this will work only in google assistant or in other integration also–

Comment: Earlier issue was dependencies were old updated those and used below code to read city and it worked 
 agent.request_.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.device.location.city;  in what all integrations will it work ?